# How can I test that an EmitterProcessor is receiving and emitting a message from a RestController?

Tags: spring-webflux, spock, spring-cloud-stream

### Setup

I have a Spring Cloud Stream application with a Controller configured very much like [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources)

Full minimum example [here](https://github.com/dmarmugi/so66341268)

```java
@Controller
public class BootstrapController {
    final EmitterProcessor<String> processor = EmitterProcessor.create();

    @RequestMapping("/bootstrap")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    public void delegateToSupplier(@RequestBody String body) {
        processor.onNext(body);
    }

    @Bean //This is the Spring Cloud Stream function
    public Supplier<Flux<Integer>> bootstrap(){
        return () -> processor.flatMap( trigger -> Flux.just(1, 2, 3));
    }

}
```

### Question

This works in practice, but I can't figure out how to put a test together that proves it (I use Spock)

I've tried variations like this, but they all just hit the timeout and fail:

#### Example 1

```
def "POST to bootstrap emits an event to processor"(){
    when:
    webTestClient.post().uri("/bootstrap").body(BodyInserters.fromValue("test"))
        .exchange()

    then:
    controller.processor.blockFirst(Duration.ofSeconds(1)) == "test"
}
```

#### Example 2

```
def "POST to bootstrap emits an event to processor"(){
    expect:
    StepVerifier.create(controller.processor)
        .then({webTestClient.post().uri("/bootstrap").body(BodyInserters.fromValue("test"))
                .exchange()})
        .expectNext("test")
        .expectComplete()
        .verify(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all your EmitterProcessor doesn't seem to be connected to anything. Second It is also deprecated and we will be updating documentation shortly.

But for your case you can make things much simpler by using [StreamBridge](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources) and then use the [TestBinder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_testing) to do the testing.
Here is the [sample test case](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/function/ScenarioTests.java) where you can see the test setup. I am not familiar with Spock, but i guess you can retrofit it somehow.

Comment: Hi Oleg, thanks for responding. To your first point: I updated the question with a link to a full example -- previously not shown was the emitterProcessor being connected to the Spring Cloud Stream function bean. To your second point, when I looked at this a few weeks ago, there still wasn't a Spring Cloud Stream version with the new Sinks API available. Regarding the StreamBridge: the rest of the app is pretty fully reactive so I figured the emitterProcessor would be more in keeping with the theme.